# how to prevent adding the same product 2 times in the shopping cart

Tags: javascript, html

Can you please tell me what i did wrong in js code ...I'm trying to prevent adding the the same product twice by clicking 'add to cart' button then alert him that this product was already added in the shopping cart

JS code:

```js
function ready() {
  //REMOVE THE SHOPPING ITEM FROM THE CART

  var removeCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')
  for (var i = 0; i < removeCartItemButtons.length; i++) {
    var button = removeCartItemButtons[i]
    button.addEventListener('click', removeCartItem)
  }

  var quantityInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')
  for (var i = 0; i < quantityInputs.length; i++) {
    var input = quantityInputs[i]
    input.addEventListener('change', quantityChanged)
  }

  var addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('add-to-cart')
  for (var i = 0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++) {
    var button = addToCartButtons[i]
    button.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked)
  }
}

function addToCartClicked(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  var button = event.target
  var shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement
  var title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-title')[0].innerText
  var price = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('new-price')[0].innerText
  var image = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('img')[0].src
  addItemToCart(title, price, image)
}
//Add the product to the shopping Cart
function addItemToCart(title, price, image) {
  var cartRow = document.createElement('div')
  var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
  var cartItemsNames = cartItems.getElementsByClassName('cart-title')
  //prevent the same product to be added twice
  for (var i = 0; i < cartItemsNames.length; i++) {
    if (cartItemsNames[i].innerText == title) {
      alert('error')
      return
    }
  }
  var cartRowContents = `
<div class="sin-itme clearfix cart-row">
<i class="mdi mdi-close btn-danger"><a href="#"></a></i>
<a class="cart-img" href="cart.html"><img src="${image}" alt="" /></a>
<div class="menu-cart-text">
<h5 class="cart-title">${title}</h5>
<span class="product-color">Color : Black</span>
<span class="product-size">Size : SL</span>
<label for="quantity" class="quantity-text">Quantity: </label>
<input type="text" class="cart-quantity-input" name="quantity" type="number" value="1">

<strong class="price">${price}</strong>
</div>
</div>
`
  cartRow.innerHTML = cartRowContents
  cartItems.append(cartRow)
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>shopping cart</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="cart-items">
    <div class="sin-itme clearfix cart-row">
      <i class="mdi mdi-close btn-danger"></i>
      <a class="cart-img" href="cart.html"><img src="img/cart/2.png" alt="" /></a>
      <div class="menu-cart-text">
        <h5 class="cart-title">product1</h5>
        <label for="quantity" class="quantity-text">Quantity: </label>
        <input type="text" class="cart-quantity-input" name="quantity" type="number" value="1">
        <strong class="price">$12.00</strong>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row shop-item">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="list-img">
        <div class="product-img">
          <div class="pro-type">
            <span>new</span>
          </div>
          <a href="#"><img src="img/products/13.jpg" class="img" alt="Product Title" /></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
      <div class="list-text">
        <h3 class="shop-title">product1</h3>
        <h5><span class="new-price">$69.30</span><del class="old-price">$79.30</del></h5>
        <div class="list-btn">
          <a href="#" class="add-to-cart" data-id="4">add to cart</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the code what i did...can you please tell me what i did wrong in JS ?...thanks

Comment: I would expect that if I click the same item twice, I would just increase the amount of the same item to order by one (and be able to decrease it again as well ). PS: Make sure you validate all prices in the backend as well. Else I'm going to add extra html nodes to the DOM when visiting that shop, but with price set at 0 dollars. ;)

Answer (score 0):

ready function in code snippet not run,you have to call it at the bottom.

in addToCartClicked function, just use document instead shopItem

```
function addToCartClicked(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  var title = document.getElementsByClassName('shop-title')[0].innerText
  var price = document.getElementsByClassName('new-price')[0].innerText
  var image = document.getElementsByClassName('img')[0].src
  addItemToCart(title, price, image)
}
```

in addItemToCart function just use document instead cartItems

```
function addItemToCart(title, price, image) {
  var cartRow = document.createElement('div')
  var cartItemsNames = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-title')
  //prevent the same product to be added twice
  for (let i = 0; i < cartItemsNames.length; i++) {
    if (cartItemsNames[i].innerText == title) {
      alert('error')
      return
    }
  }
  // ....
  // ....
}
```

The above changes are just to make your code clearer.

```js
function ready() {
  //REMOVE THE SHOPPING ITEM FROM THE CART

  var removeCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')
  for (var i = 0; i < removeCartItemButtons.length; i++) {
    var button = removeCartItemButtons[i]
    // button.addEventListener('click', removeCartItem)
  }

  var quantityInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')
  for (var i = 0; i < quantityInputs.length; i++) {
    var input = quantityInputs[i]
    // input.addEventListener('change', quantityChanged)
  }

  var addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('add-to-cart')
  for (var i = 0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++) {
    var button = addToCartButtons[i]
    button.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked)
  }
}

function addToCartClicked(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  console.log(123)
  var title = document.getElementsByClassName('shop-title')[0].innerText
  var price = document.getElementsByClassName('new-price')[0].innerText
  var image = document.getElementsByClassName('img')[0].src
  addItemToCart(title, price, image)
}
//Add the product to the shopping Cart
function addItemToCart(title, price, image) {
  var cartRow = document.createElement('div')
  var cartItemsNames = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-title')
  //prevent the same product to be added twice
  for (let i = 0; i < cartItemsNames.length; i++) {
    if (cartItemsNames[i].innerText == title) {
      alert('error')
      return
    }
  }
  var cartRowContents = `
<div class="sin-itme clearfix cart-row">
<i class="mdi mdi-close btn-danger"><a href="#"></a></i>
<a class="cart-img" href="cart.html"><img src="${image}" alt="" /></a>
<div class="menu-cart-text">
<h5 class="cart-title">${title}</h5>
<span class="product-color">Color : Black</span>
<span class="product-size">Size : SL</span>
<label for="quantity" class="quantity-text">Quantity: </label>
<input type="text" class="cart-quantity-input" name="quantity" type="number" value="1">

<strong class="price">${price}</strong>
</div>
</div>
`
  cartRow.innerHTML = cartRowContents
  cartItems.append(cartRow)
}
ready()
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>shopping cart</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="cart-items">
    <div class="sin-itme clearfix cart-row">
      <i class="mdi mdi-close btn-danger"></i>
      <a class="cart-img" href="cart.html"><img src="img/cart/2.png" alt="" /></a>
      <div class="menu-cart-text">
        <h5 class="cart-title">product1</h5>
        <label for="quantity" class="quantity-text">Quantity: </label>
        <input type="text" class="cart-quantity-input" name="quantity" type="number" value="1">
        <strong class="price">$12.00</strong>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row shop-item">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="list-img">
        <div class="product-img">
          <div class="pro-type">
            <span>new</span>
          </div>
          <a href="#"><img src="img/products/13.jpg" class="img" alt="Product Title" /></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
      <div class="list-text">
        <h3 class="shop-title">product1</h3>
        <h5><span class="new-price">$69.30</span><del class="old-price">$79.30</del></h5>
        <div class="list-btn">
          <a href="#" class="add-to-cart" data-id="4">add to cart</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: unfortunately still the same problem...the if statement doesn't work in the for loop when the second press on 'add to cart' button  on the same product it should alert the user by pop-up alert message...that's what it should be....I tried many ways to solve it but still doesn't work..